# What is fcm’s fan-out and how do I measure the number of fan-outs?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implements fcm fan-out throttling systems.

Following this docs, there is 1000 fan-outs limit per project .
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#fanout_throttling

But I don't get the count of fan-outs.
Is it the number of users that I want to send a message?
Or count of messages that I want to send multiple users.
For example, I want to send different messages each to two group.
Group One have 100 users, Group Two have 10 users.
So fcm's fan-out count is two or 110?

I'm trying to understand that meaning of the fan-out in software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Message fanout is the process of sending a message to multiple devices, such as when you target topics and groups, or when you use the Notifications composer to target audiences or user segments.

So a fanout happens when you target multiple devices with a single API call, such as when you send a topic, or when you target audiences or user segments through the Firebase console.

From that same documentation, comes this on the limit you mention:

> Message fanout is not instantaneous and so occasionally you have multiple fanouts in progress concurrently. **We limit the number of *concurrent* message fanouts per project to 1,000.**

Note the word "concurrent" in there, which you missed in your interpretation. So this is about the number of fanout operations that are going on at the same time. In normal sized and even quite large projects you are *very* unlikely to ever reach this limit.

---

In your example it's not clear what "sending to a group" means in terms of API calls or console actions, but if a group is implemented as a topic, an audience, or a user segment, the total counts as two fanout operations.

If you execute these at the same time, you may for a time have two concurrent fanouts going on. If you execute them one after the other, it's just one concurrent fanout. Either way, this type of operation is *far* below any limit where you'll get throttled.